# How do I compare multiple column values of 2 different csv files and get a similarity ratio in python?

Tags: python, csv

I am looking for something with which I can pick multiple columns of 2 different csv files in python, compare the column values and get the similarity ratio for each value in a separate file.

Comment: Check out the ```csv-diff``` library, it might do the job. Link: https://pypi.org/project/csv-diff/

Comment: This won't give a similarity ratio I guess